# Toggle between hide and show in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a textbox initially now when I change the dropdown value it is replaced with another dropdown.
Now When i again changed back to original value that dropdown still remains same rather than it is made visible for a particular condition only.

here is my code

```
$('#service_id').on('change', function () {
        var service_id = $('#service_id option:selected').text();
        if (service_id=='To Airport') 
        {
            alert(service_id);
            $('#dropoff_at').hide();
            $('#dropoff_at_airport').show();
        }

        else if(service_id=='From Airport')
        {
            alert(service_id);
            $('#pickup_at').hide();
            $('#pickup_at_airport').show();
        }
        else
        {
            alert(service_id);
        }


    });
 });
```

Where service_id is dropdown from where values will be changed.

HTML Code

```
<div class="col-sm-6 pull-right quote-form">
                <div class="full-width-container">
                    <label>Select Service</label>

                    <select name="service_id" id="service_id">
                    <?php if(!empty($services)){
                        foreach ($services as $key => $value) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $value->id ?>"><?php echo $value->service_name ?></option>
                    <?php }} ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="full-width-container">
                    <label>Passengers</label>
                    <select name="no_of_passengers">
                        <?php for ($i=1; $i <=100 ; $i++) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="full-width-container">
                    <label>Pickup Time</label>
                    <div class="small-input"> 
                        <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="pickup_date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-select">
                         <input type="text" class="timepicker" name="pickup_time">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="full-width-container">
                    <label>Pickup At</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pickup_at" name="pickup_at">
                    <select name="pickup_at" id="pickup_at_airport" style="display:none">
                    <?php if(!empty($airport)){
                        foreach ($airport as $key => $value) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $value->id ?>"><?php echo $value->name ?></option>
                    <?php }} ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="full-width-container">
                    <label>Dropoff At</label>
                    <input type="text" id="dropoff_at" name="dropoff_at">
                    <select name="dropoff_at" id="dropoff_at_airport" style="display:none">
                    <?php if(!empty($airport)){
                        foreach ($airport as $key => $value) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $value->id ?>"><?php echo $value->name ?></option>
                    <?php }} ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: what does this alert(service_id) shows?

Comment: nothing it is just for debugging, to get the text of service_id

Comment: doesnt it shows any alert?? i am asking about it

Comment: yes obv it shows m going correct in there infact the show hide works perfectly I only have issues after that

Comment: what issue after that?

Comment: I have a textbox initially now when I change the dropdown value it is replaced with another dropdown. "Now When i again changed back to original value that dropdown still remains same rather than it is made visible for a particular condition only."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be ok if you hide previously shown things when select the other option.

```
if (service_id=='To Airport') 
{
    alert(service_id);
    $('#dropoff_at').hide();
    $('#dropoff_at_airport').show();
    $('#pickup_at').show();
    $('#pickup_at_airport').hide();
}
else if(service_id=='From Airport')
{
    alert(service_id);
    $('#pickup_at').hide();
    $('#pickup_at_airport').show();
    $('#dropoff_at').show();
    $('#dropoff_at_airport').hide();
}
```

Comment: Should the order be  `hide()`, `show()`, `show()`, `hide()` for both, as when we are going to the airport, for instance, we need to enter the `#pickup_at` data.

Comment: Of course! I edited the answer as that. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selectedIndex` to 0 before show the dropdown.

```
 $('#dropoff_at_airport').prop('selectedIndex',0);
 $('#dropoff_at_airport').show();
```

It reset your drop down and previous selected value loose on focus.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#service_id').change(function () {
        var service_id = $(this).val();
        if (service_id=='To Airport')
        {
            alert(service_id);
            $('#dropoff_at').hide();
            $('#dropoff_at_airport').show();
        }

        else if(service_id=='From Airport')
        {
            alert(service_id);
            $('#pickup_at').hide();
            $('#pickup_at_airport').show();
        }
        else
        {
            alert(service_id);
        }


    });
```